# Determinant and Linearly Independent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Question**: Let $A\in M_{3\times3}$ and $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3$. If $x,y,z$ are linearly independent and we have that,

$Ax = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}, Ay=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix},Az=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Find the determinant of A.

I noticed that $Ax+Ay=Az$, but I am not sure of what this tells me about A to help me find its determinant.

Comment: Hint:  $A(x+y-z)=0$.

Comment: @lulu from this I can conclude that since $x +y-z \ne 0$, $A$ must transform $x +y-z$ to $0$, which means the determinant is $0$. Is that corrrect?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If a linear map has a non-trivial kernel, that is, if it sends a non-zero vector to $0$, then it has a determinant of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $A$ is invertible, it maps a basis onto a basis.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $Ax+Ay=Az$ tells you that the set $\{Ax,Ay,Az\}$ is not linearly independent. Therefore, that determinant that you're after is equal to $0$.

Comment: Why does that tell me the determinant is $0$? Can I also say that since $x +y-z \ne 0$, $A$ must transform $x +y-z$ to $0$, which means the determinant is $0$?

Comment: This tells you that the determinant is $0$ because the determinant of the matrix of a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ into itself is $0$ if and only if that map is injective. But an njective linear map maps linearly independent sets into linearly independent sets And, yes, you can also say that $x+y-z\neq0$, but $A(x+y-z)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i \\
\end{array}
\right)$
where entries are in $\mathbb{R}$
Linear Independence 
$a_1 \text{Σ}\left[x_i\right]+a_2 \text{ Σ}\left[y_i\right]+a_3 \text{ Σ}\left[z_i\right]=0$    -----(A)
$\Rightarrow a_1=a_2=a_3=0$
$a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$
$\text{Ax}+\text{Ay}+\text{Az}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\
 2 \\
 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
$a \text{Σ}\left[x_i\right]+b \text{ Σ}\left[y_i\right]+c \text{ Σ}\left[z_i\right]=0$    -----(B)
$d \text{Σ}\left[x_i\right]+e \text{ Σ}\left[y_i\right]+f \text{ Σ}\left[z_i\right]=0$ 
$g \text{Σ}\left[x_i\right]+h \text{ Σ}\left[y_i\right]+i \text{ Σ}\left[z_i\right]=0$ 
$\implies 0\neq 2$
All entries are zero
$\therefore |A|=0$